# Place an image next to each dynamic div created

Tags: javascript, css

i am creating with this function some dynamic div. The function is working, but i want to contain one same image in front of each innerHTML name. how is this possible?
thanks in advance

```
function createdivbusiness(returned_data){
    var output = document.getElementById("business");
       for (var i=0; i<returned_data.name.length; i++){
            var element = document.createElement("div");
            element.setAttribute("id",'business'+i);
            element.setAttribute("tabIndex","0");
            element.setAttribute("class","styled-business");
            element.innerHTML=returned_data.name[i];
            output.appendChild(element); 

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do like this

```
element.innerHTML= "<img src='path_to_image' alt='some text'>" +  returned_data.name[i];
```